# How can I add an insert action to a grid row level on the mobile app?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen which has a header and detail (grid) - and there are several levels in the mobile app to navigate through to get to the tab/section with the grid.  Once in the grid, I can't see a way to insert a row IF there aren't any existing rows.  I've used the following code (Agenda is the container area for the grid level):

```
add container "Agenda" {
    add field "AgendaID"
    add field "Duration"
    add field "AssignedTo"{
      textType = PlainMultiLine
    }
    add field "Status"
    add field "Category"
    add field "Topic"{
       textType = PlainMultiLine
    }
    add field "Comments"{
       textType = PlainMultiLine
    }
    add field "Details"{
        textType = PlainMultiLine
    }    
    add recordAction "Save" {
        behavior = Save
    }    
    add recordAction "Cancel" {
        behavior = Cancel
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
        behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
        behavior = Create
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm not doing this right, but the ellipse for the delete/save etc. on the bottom right doesn't show up unless there is already a row existing.

Comment: Did you try adding an icon? Something like this:  add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
   add recordAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Another"
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }

Comment: Also adding these at the top of your container: add container "Agenda" {
    fieldsToShow = 3
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1 ....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compliments of cbetabeta (thanks much):

Add containerAction "Insert" { icon = "system://Plus" behavior = Create } add recordAction "Insert" { displayName = "Add Another" icon = "system://Plus" behavior = Create }

Also adding these at the top of your container: add container "Agenda" { fieldsToShow = 3 formActionsToExpand = 2 containerActionsToExpand = 1